# Can't get Table Data from Site After the Page Loads

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to obtain the 2nd table on the following website. I've tried BS4, Pandas, and now selenium, but I can't obtain the table for the life of me.

The table data doesn't load until after the page comes up.

There is a dictionary on the 'view source' page with the info, but its seems like every element on that page is 'line-content', so its makes it difficult to obtain only the desired table info.

What is the best way to collect the table data?

```
from ast import Return
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
import time

path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

driver.get('https://www.linestarapp.com/Ownership/Sport/NFL/Site/DraftKings/PID/295')

time.sleep(5)
driver.maximize_window()

time.sleep(5)

players = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('playerRow').text
print(players)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here:

1. `find_elements_by_class_name` method returns a **list** of web elements. You can not apply `.text` method on a list of web elements, you need to iterate over elements in a list and extract text from each element one by one.
2. You should not use hardcoded pauses like `time.sleep(5)` Expected Conditions explicitly waits should be used instead.
   Something like this:

```py
from ast import Return
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get('https://www.linestarapp.com/Ownership/Sport/NFL/Site/DraftKings/PID/295')

driver.maximize_window()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".playerRow")))
#short pause added in order to make sure all the elements are loaded after we know the first element was loaded
time.sleep(0.5)

players = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('playerRow')
for player in players:
    print(player.text)
```

**UPD**
Using this css_selector locator `#tableTournament .playerRow` instead of just `.playerRow`will give you the right table rows

Comment: thank you so much. this worked.  it did obtain both tables however. is there a way to only obtain the 'playerRows' of the 2nd table? or would i just need create a condition after they're all obtained?

Comment: You will need to correct the locator. I will take a moment to see that

Comment: What do you mean by second table only? The table on the right side starting with Devin Singletary?

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to your problem might be to query for the second table by id, and only later get the table row elements.

```
from selenium import webdriver
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
 
driver.get('https://www.linestarapp.com/Ownership/Sport/NFL/Site/DraftKings/PID/295')

driver.maximize_window()

# the first table has id projectedTournament
secondTable = driver.find_element_by_id("tableTournament")

players = secondTable.find_elements_by_class_name('playerRow')
for playerRowElement in players:
    for playerColumn in playerRowElement.find_elements_by_tag_name("td"):
        print(playerColumn.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative to Selenium, the table is in the html actually in the `<script>` tag.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re
import json

url = 'https://www.linestarapp.com/Ownership/Sport/NFL/Site/DraftKings/PID/295'

response = requests.get(url)

p = 'var actualResultsDict = ({*.})'

replaceDict = {"'":'"', 
               'id': '"id"',
               'name':'"name"',
               'owned':'"owned"',
               'pos':'"pos"',
               'team':'"team"',
               'sal':'"sal"'}

jsonStr = re.search(r'var actualResultsDict = {([\w\W]*)function posMatch', response.text, re.M).group(1)

for key, value in replaceDict.items():
    jsonStr = jsonStr.replace(key, value)
    
jsonStrSplit = jsonStr.split('],')    

jsonData = {}
for idx, each in enumerate(jsonStrSplit[:-1]):
    temp = '{' + each.rsplit(',',1)[0] + ']}'
    tempData = json.loads(temp)
    
    jsonData.update(tempData)
    
    
rows = []
for k,v in jsonData.items():
    rows += v

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
       id                   name  owned pos team   sal
0    5942       Devin Singletary  37.31  RB  BUF  5900
1    7303      Ja&#39;Marr Chase  33.57  WR  CIN  7100
2    7658           Eli Mitchell  28.31  RB   SF  5800
3    3612          Derrick Henry  26.93  RB  TEN  7500
4    2142          Davante Adams  26.25  WR   GB  8500
..    ...                    ...    ...  ..  ...   ...
108  6895  Nick Westbrook-Ikhine   1.72  WR  TEN  3800
109  6006          Scotty Miller   1.70  WR   TB  3300
110  4453     D&#39;Onta Foreman   1.64  RB  TEN  5200
111  2403            Geoff Swaim   1.36  TE  TEN  2800
112  5359      Dontrell Hilliard   1.08  RB  TEN  4300

[113 rows x 6 columns]
```